# XV6 os - Docker ubuntu image error: "no bootable device" / qemu-nox command

Tags: windows, docker, qemu

I am trying to run the XV6 OS on ubuntu image in a docker container (on windows).
I succeed in building the image, running it and accessing the docker container.
But inside the container cmd when I try to use the `make qemu-nox` command it crashes and gives the following error:

```
SeaBIOS (version 1.13.0-1ubuntu1)
iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+1FF8CA10+1FECCA10 CA00
Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: not a bootable disk
No bootable device.
```

I am following the instructions here: https://github.com/anton-christensen/xv6-docker

I am not sure what causes this. 
The other commands such as `make`, `make clean qemu` does work without error.

Comment: It is telling you that the disk image it passes to qemu is not bootable, you'd most likely have to track down how that image is constructed to resolve the issue.

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt, yes okay I see. Will try to dive more into that

Answer (score 0):

For some reason a moderator deleted my comment after I spent almost an hour researching this and found a solution (I'm sensing a conspiracy here... my bet is SO's servers are running on xv6 and they don't want anyone else to be able to run it)

This is an issue in xv6. The issue can be solved by using the following PR: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/pull/115

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.